# DocumentDB how to add an array of all documents sharing same value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aws-documentdb

I have a collection with documents following this structure:

```js
{
  _id: 11,
  tx_id: "a",
  amount: 12,
  order_id: 1
},
{
  _id: 22,
  tx_id: "b",
  amount: 11,
  order_id: 1
},
{
  _id: 33,
  tx_id: "c",
  amount: 4,
  order_id: 2
}
```

And I want to add a field `relatedTxs` with all the transactions sharing the same `order_id` as the parent, something like:

```js
{
  _id: 11,
  tx_id: "a",
  amount: 12,
  order_id: 1
  relatedTxs: [
    {
      _id: 11,
      tx_id: "a",
      amount: 12,
      order_id: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 22,
      tx_id: "b",
      amount: 11,
      order_id: 1
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 22,
  tx_id: "b",
  amount: 11,
  order_id: 1
  relatedTxs: [
    {
      _id: 11,
      tx_id: "a",
      amount: 12,
      order_id: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 22,
      tx_id: "b",
      amount: 11,
      order_id: 1
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 33,
  tx_id: "c",
  amount: 4,
  order_id: 2
  relatedTxs: [
    {
      _id: 33,
      tx_id: "c",
      amount: 4,
      order_id: 2
    }
  ]
}
```

The order of the related transactions array doesn't matter and including the parent is optional. Even the format is not required to be that one, I just need the whole document info and an array inside with all the info about the transactions sharing the same `order_id`.

I managed to accomplish that with a `$lookup` to the same collection, but the performance is really poor.

The `order_id` field has an index, and the database is DocumentDB.

Is there any way to do the same thing without a lookup? Maybe using `$group`? Thank you very much!

Comment: you can group as follow: https://mongoplayground.net/p/-DciCtCkOUi

Comment: The only problem with that is that I'd still need to iterate all the results in my code to get the unique transactions. This is for returning data for a table. So I need one object per transaction, with it's related transactions inside. That's why in the post I added the field instead of just grouping and replacing the whole doc @R2D2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query1

- you can do a self-lookup with pipeline
- pipeline filter to keep only those with same `order_id` and then groups to put them inside an array
- the last `$set` is to fix the structure to get the first element from the lookup array and the field, to make them not-nested like in your expected output
- to make it faster create an index on `order_id`

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63724823424f6130d7f12163)

```js
coll.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
   {"from": "coll",
    "pipeline": 
     [{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$order_id", "$$order_id"]}}},
       {"$group": {"_id": "$order_id", "relatedTxs": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}}}],
    "as": "relatedTxs",
    "let": {"order_id": "$order_id"}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"relatedTxs": 
     {"$getField": 
       {"field": "relatedTxs", "input": {"$first": "$relatedTxs"}}}}}])
```

Query2 (without pipeline `$lookup`)

- group by `order_id` and collect both the documents
- duplicate the array in a temp-array
- unwind
- replace the root with each unwinded document

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63724c33424f6130d7f12164)

```js
coll.aggregate(
[{"$group": {"_id": "$order_id", "orders-temp": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$set": {"orders": "$orders-temp"}}, {"$unwind": "$orders-temp"},
 {"$replaceRoot": 
   {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$orders-temp", "$$ROOT"]}}},
 {"$unset": ["orders-temp", "_id"]}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, I'm not using genuine MongoDB but DocumentDB. And it does not support uncorrelated subqueries in lookup... Maybe I should change the title instead of just specifying it in the question. My bad. Do you have any ideas without lookup? Thanks!

Comment: i added one more with group only, i think its ok check it to be sure

Comment: Thank you very much!! The second query did the trick! I had to do some minor changes to match a couple more restrictions, but the group + undwind is perfect, thanks!!!